# How to get the custom endpoint URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom endpoint and i am also able to view it on the browser by visiting http://localhost/wordpress/contactus.

Now, I am having problem finding a proper way to create a hyperlink to visit the page. I searched all over the internet but didn't able to find a solution to it.

Edit: I have used this post 
https://return-true.com/creating-a-custom-page-with-wordpress-endpoints/ for creating custom endpoint but it didn't tel, how to create the url /dump programatically?
I want to know if there is any specific function in wordpress like get_permalink() or so to fetch the url of a custom endpoint?

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information. Please check, if you can understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to WordPress, but HTML in general:

```
<a href="http://localhost/wordpress/contactus">Link Text Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt `get_site_url()` to get the full url and then append `/dump` to create the hyperlink. Something like below :

`<a href='<? echo get_site_url().'/dump'?>'>My Link</a>`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/